# Convention on how pass multiple regexps on command line

Tags: regex, command-line-interface

I'm writing a small command line utility that will need to take several arguments each of which can be a list of regular expressions. Is there a convention on how to do that?

Here is an example of what I have in mind

```
mycliutility -i regexp1,regexp2 -o regexp3,regexp4 somefilename
```

so I'm asking if for example a comma is good separtor for the regexpression and what/how to escape that if the separator need to appear in the regexp.

I'm expecting/hoping that the need to use comma (or whatever) in the regexp is rare so I would like to use a syntax that is as as light weight as possible.

Pointer to existing cli tools that take arguments like that are welcome.

EDIT

It is also possible that the regexps come from a Java Properties file and for this reason if would be 'cleaner' if multiple rexeps on the command line were treated as one (so the syntax would be the same on CLI and the properties file), see this example.properties file:

iexps = regexp1,regexp2
oexps = regexp3,regexp4

Comment: Indicating which programming language or platform you are using would enable us to write a much better, more specific answer.

Comment: Its Java but I don't think that makes a difference cause I'm not considering the implementation difficulties or easiness as a factor in this decision, this should be based solely on the user's convenience only, including conforming to common conventions.

Comment: But different tools have different syntax.  A tool which uses `sed` internally has a much more constrained regex syntax, so you have a wider choice of available separators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the regexes are simple alternatives, a single regex of the form `regex1|regex2` may well be the simplest solution.

If you need to parse comma-separated regexes out of the property file anyway, you'd better use the same syntax on the command line as well. Game over.

One thing I thought of, but don't really recommend, is to wrap the regex inside a pair of delimiters, outside of which a comma delimiter would be unambiguous. Slashes are popular as regex delimiters in `sed`, Awk, Perl, and PHP; but PHP should act as a warning example, because the `preg_replace` syntax has a pesky problem with double quoting (`"/regex/"` is a regex between slash delimiters inside a double-quoted string).

---

No, a comma is not a good separator, because it can validly occur inside a regular expression.

My recommendation would be to use an option parser which allows you to specify the same option name multiple times, so you can say

```
mycliutility -i regexp1 -i regexp2 -o regexp3 -o regexp4 somefilename
```

If your implementation language is Python and you are using [`optparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html), for example, look at the `action='append'` behavior.

Comment: What can't occur validly inside a reg expression ;) ?

I kind of like your suggestion … is there a precedent for this, surely I cannot be the first one to write a cli tool that takes multiple regular expressions as parameters.

Comment: `grep -e regex1 -e regex2`

Comment: `{}` I think would be invalid in most regexen but it has connotations in other tools, notably `xargs` and `find` (oh, and Python). And of course, inside a character class it's not only possible, but quite likely if the character class enumerates paired delimiters.

Comment: But of course you could also say `grep -E 'regex1|regex2'` for much the same effect.

Comment: One in the eye the example 'grep -e regex1 -e regex2' LOL. 
Just realised my question lacks a (self inflicted) constraint, I will edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: actually, your suggestion
grep -E 'regex1|regex2' would work for the properties file case, why have multiple regexps when one can match multiple strings? How short sighted of me, if you put that in your answer I will accept that as the credit belongs to you...